# How to transfer HTML-String from component.ts to component.html

Tags: angular

I would like to ask how to transfer a HTML format string from the `.component.ts` file into the `.component.html` file.

In my App there is a layout folder. The `layout.component.ts` file has the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})

export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlText: string;

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.htmlText = '<b>title</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>';
  }
}
```

Both the text and its HTML format are defined. Thus I want to show the text with its own HTML-defination in the browser.

The `layout.component.html` file looks like:

```
<h2>{{ htmlText }}</h2>
```

After compiling the browser shows the full text of the htmlText string, but the HTML format was just ignored.

What have I done wrong? Thanks for any kind of hint+help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a pipe with the following code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
switch (type) {
    case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
}
}
}
```

and in the html file use the following line of code:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlBody | keepHtml: 'html'"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use [innerHTML]

`<div [innerHtml]="htmlText"></div>`

That would be enough.