# Open HTML plain text in new window or else

Tags: angular, oauth, angular7

I'm getting a full HTML page code after hitting an API endpoint via get. This is for authentication purposes, the HTML I get from the endpoint is a social network login form which the user needs to fill in to authenticate.

```
this.http
    .get('api/endpoint/html', { responseType: 'text' })
    .pipe(map((html: string) => {
      const popup = window.open('', 'Page', `toolbar=no,location=no ...`);
      
      popup.document.open();
      popup.document.write(html);
    }));
```

The page seems to work, it displays the page, the form should make a post and return to a previously configured "after login url" with some parameters, but when I filled my credentials an error is been thrown.

```
Cannot POST /my/redirect/after/login/url
```

Which I'm guessing is because I loaded the popup by doing a document.write(html) in the first place.

Is there any way to load the HTML I got from the API call in a popup window and get the login form works?

Thanks in advance.

---

## #**UPDATE**

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636615/webpack-not-accepting-post-requests) I think I know what's happening. Now, the accepted answer indicates that a webpack configuration must be done, how to do such configuration for an Angular7 app?

Because when creating the project I only have an angular.json file for holding all webpack configuration stuffs, and it doesn't allow me to write such a configuration.

Comment: Ok, Thanks to this post ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636615/webpack-not-accepting-post-requests ) I think I know what's happening. Now, how to do such configuration for an Angular7 app ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following answer:
[How to transfer HTML-String from component.ts to component.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764573/how-to-transfer-html-string-from-component-ts-to-component-html/49764617#49764617)

Below is the code snippet for your reference:

create a pipe with the following code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
switch (type) {
    case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
}
}
}
```

and in the html file use the following line of code:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlBody | keepHtml: 'html'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @praveen-kumar, will it work with a complete page html code. What I get from the API is every thing, starting from <DOCTYPE> <html>... it includes even styles and javascript within

Comment: Yes, it does. Refer to the stackblitz url for implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o1nu4n